# need to replace my old Dell Vostro l/top with a S/H one, older software I run will only work on Windows XPSP3 - will the newer I5 processors run XP

Tags: windows, windows-xp

I need to replace my old Dell Vostro l/top with a S/H one, The older software I run will only work on Windows XP-SP3 - will the newer I5 processors run XP

Comment: Use a VM, e.g., https://www.virtualbox.org/n. There is not room on this site for a complete tutorial on VM's, so read what's online. As for installing software, it is a new machine, so you *certainly* need to install software on it.

Answer (score 1):

> will the newer I5 processors run XP

Very most likely not (greater than 95% if not 100%).

Your only choice here is to run XP as a Virtual Machine.

I use VMware Workstation Pro V17 and have and XP Pro machine that works fine. VirtualBox is another choice.

But a Virtual Machine is the only practical choice going forward.

To do this, you need the XP DVD and then in the Virtual Machine App, use File New Machine, and install the ISO. You can make almost any VM this way.